# Is there any way to detect electric current sound when using aaudio

Tags: android, audio

Many android devices has incompatibility problem with AAudio, such as silenced, noise, etc.
for example, please see this video(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13726257/209959288-2f8105ea-9215-427b-93df-0356637d6172.mp4), from 20th seconds, you can hear my sound with obvious noise.

Is there is a way to detect that? In addition, how to express this kind of noise more accurately in technical term? I use "electric current sound" before, but not sure its ok.